# How to know which phone number Whatsapp is using on my phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

On my phone I used my T-mobile number as well as my Google voice number. I registered to Whatsapp using my Google voice number. How can I check in Whatsapp which number it uses?

I use a Samsung Galaxy S5 (SM-G900A) with Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number WhatsApp uses is the one you registered with; to see it go to menu (the three dots at the top right corner) -> account -> payment info and there you will see which number is associated with the WhatsApp account.

EDIT: Since WhatsApp removed the payment, it is possible to check the connected number by opening the settings menu and tapping on the badge displaying name, status and profile picture.

Comment: There is no more "Payment Info" item under Account with the latest version (I'm looking at 2.17.24)

Comment: @friederbluemle thank you for pointing this out, edited my answer.

Comment: Go to settings and click on your profile picture on the top. It will take you to another screen where you can see it after the "about".